# Raw SQL on Airflow

Tags: jobs, airflow

I'd prefer to use raw SQL ( Mainly select + insert ) instead of O/R mapper, because it would be difficult to perform queries.

(The RDBMS is postgres9.4)

So the question is

Can I use raw SQL for logic part in Airflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create tasks that run raw SQL in a Postgres database directly using the [PostgresOperator](https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/code.html#airflow.operators.PostgresOperator). You will need to set up your Postgres database as a [Connection object](https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/concepts.html#connections) in order for Airflow to know how to connect to the database.